# Selecting a sibling of a parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got this HTML:

```
<font>
   <b>
      <a href="profile/user">user</a>
   </b>
   <font>message</font>
</font>
```

I know the font tag sucks, but they wanted font tags so I put font tags.
I can select the user's name with

`a[href*="user"]`

but I want to be able to select the font containing the message, too. Is that possible with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot select the parent with CSS - you might find this an interesting read on the topic: [Why we don't have a parent selector](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors). However, you can do one of the following:

**1.** Use a bit of JavaScript

**2.** Change your HTML to

```
<font>
   <a href="profile/user"><b>user</b></a>
   <font>message</font>
</font>
```

and you can do this:

```
a[href*="user"] + font { /* YOUR STYLES HERE */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot move a level up to an element´s parent using CSS.